# Python Pandas Resampling ipython kernel died unexpectedly Error

Tags: python, pandas

I got `ipython kernel died unexpectedly Error`, when I am trying to resample my data with 1 second interval. The `index_result` is about 60000000 rows by 15 columns with datetime object as index. There was no error when I resampled from 5 seconds to 18 hours. However, whenever I want to resample it with 1 second interval, it gave me `kernel died unexpectely error`.

The following is the code:

```
resample_interval= ['1S','5S','10S','15S','30S','60S','90S','120S','180S','240S',\
'5T','7T','10T','15T','30T','45T','1H','2H','3H','4H','6H','8H','12H','18H']

for idx,interval in enumerate(resample_interval):    
    locals()
['resample_result_'+resample_interval[idx]] = index_result.resample(resample_interval[idx], how={'Volume':np.sum, 'Ask Price':'ohlc', 'Bid Price':'ohlc', 'Price':'ohlc'})
```

Comment: I tried to resample 1S with a subset of my dataframe. It works with no error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind is Memory issue. I have a 24G RAM, but pandas here is taking large blocks of memory, because my dataframe is really large. 
My solution to this problem is to chunk the dataframe and resample piece by piece and then put them back together later on. Hope this helps if you encounter the same issue.